# pyvis Library how to convert a network graph that i all ready have from Networkx using the function nt.from_nx

Tags: python, pyvis

I'm trying to use the pyvis Library to convert a network graph that I all ready have from( Networkx ) using the function nt.from_nx [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIntn.png)

my code :

```
strong_G (graph object)

from pyvis.network import Network
import networkx as nx
nx_graph = strong_G
nt = Network("500px", "500px")
# populates the nodes and edges data structures
nt.from_nx(nx_graph)
nt.show("nx.html")
```

this is the example shown in the library

(https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#example-visualizing-a-game-of-thrones-character-network)

```
import networkx as nx
nx_graph = nx.cycle_graph(10)
nx_graph.nodes[1]['title'] = 'Number 1'
nx_graph.nodes[1]['group'] = 1
nx_graph.nodes[3]['title'] = 'I belong to a different group!'
nx_graph.nodes[3]['group'] = 10
nx_graph.add_node(20, size=20, title='couple', group=2)
nx_graph.add_node(21, size=15, title='couple', group=2)
nx_graph.add_edge(20, 21, weight=5)
nx_graph.add_node(25, size=25, label='lonely', title='lonely node', group=3)
nt = Network("500px", "500px")
# populates the nodes and edges data structures
nt.from_nx(nx_graph)
nt.show("nx.html")
```

any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: What is the error? Can you exactly replicate the example?

Answer (score 0):

I use simpler code:

```
net = Network(height="1000px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white",directed=True)
net.from_nx(strong_G,show_edge_weights=True)
net.show_buttons(filter_=['physics'])
net.show("test.html")
```